# Confused about Q and K in Attention Mechanism

Tags: transformer, attention-mechanism

The following equation computes the attention scores:

A = softmax(QK / d)

I think Q and K are interchangeable, but why is one called Query and the other called Key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is necessary to figure out what kind of attention mechanism we are talking about.

If this is a «classical» attention mechanism, then **Q** and **K** are calculated for completely different sequences: input and output.

If this is a self-attention, then, indeed, they are calculated for the same sequence, but for different tasks. **Q** – represents the token for which the attention is calculated. On the other hand, **K** – represents tokens that can be paid attention to.